# Smo EnumAvailableSqlServers does not return any data for SQl server 2012 with .net4

Tags: sql-server, smo

Smo call EnumAvailableSqlServers was working with .net3. But with .net 4 on sql server 2012 it doesnt fetch any data.

I am passing parameter as false, Let me know if i need to use another APi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with the .dll version i was using. Fixed it !